# Need help on to design architecture\model for Message send\receive using RESTFul Webservice + JMSTemplates + MQSeries

Tags: rest, ibm-mq, spring-jms

1. Need an flow diagram.
2. How we are making an synchronous between producer and receiver (using MessageID and CorrelationID).
3. using REST + Spring + MQSeries (mandatory) , i have to implement it.

Any support would be very grateful.

Thanks in Advance!!
NJ

Comment: Want to conclude this requirement : Need any sample code : Using RESTful web services passing some details to request queue and getting response from response queue using WebSphere MQ Series.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it would have been better if you asked your question more clearly and be more specific wherever you can. You can search online for info that already exists. But anyway...

If you want to build a restful service using spring, this is a good starting point:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

If you want to use spring-jms to interface with Websphere MQ, you can search online but, here's a few links to get you started:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-spring4/
and also https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/

Specifically if you are looking to make a synchronous request-response call using jms, you basically need to have the message id of the request message as the correlation id of the response message.

This link might help (you can use spring-jms to implement something similar):
http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReplyJmsExample.html

Good luck! :)